# While throwing a ball up in the air it doesn't hurt but when it comes back at same altitude it hurts why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, collision, projectile

> While throwing a ball up in the air it doesn't hurt but when it comes back at same altitude it hurts why? Well have the same amount of momentum in both of the cases. Then why does it hurt when it comes back?

My attempt : momentum of my hand and momentum of ball are in same direction. So relative or resultant momentum is zero while throwing the ball...  And in case of receiving the the momentum acts in same direction.. So resultant huge momentum does hurt..  Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume for now that there is no air friction. In this case due to the conservation of energy, the ball comes back with the same velocity. It is obvious that larger the force on the hand the more it will hurt. The change in momentum caused by the hand is same for both throwing and catching the ball. However according to Newton's second law

$$F= \frac {\Delta P}{\Delta t} $$.
 So the only variable is the time taken.
While throwing the ball your hand applies a smaller force over a longer period of time but the catching process is abrupt so the force that should be applied to stop the ball is huge. The same logic can be applied for the case with air friction as well.

Comment: So if I slowly move my hands downwards then it'll take more time and if it takes the same time as needed to throw the ball it shouldn't hurt? Just asking for clarification

Comment: Yes exactly. The same reason why high jumpers in athletics land on foam or sand. time in which they come to rest is increased that way. And momentum does not hurt or apply on anything. momentum is a property of the particle.